# D3 V3 handle touch events?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Super-simple (I hope) D3 question. I am using D3 V3. I have some paths and I want to show a D3 tooltip on **touch** events on these paths on touch devices.

I already have this working perfectly on mouseover:

```
    paths.on('mouseover', function(d) {
      tip.show(d.properties);
    }).on('mouseout', function(d) {
      tip.hide();
    })
```

Now how do I show the tooltips on touch events? I've tried adding a `touchstart` event:

```
 paths.on('mouseover', function(d) {
      tip.show(d.properties);
    }).on('touchstart', function(d) {
      tip.show(d.properties);
    }).on('mouseout', function(d) {
      tip.hide();
    });
```

But it totally doesn't do anything, at least on Chrome/Android.

Comment: Could you find the solution?